# How to disable SSLv3 in Apache?

Tags: ssl, apache-httpd

Everybody seems to be talking about the [POODLE vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability) today. And everybody recommends disabling SSLv3 in Apache using the following configuration directive:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

instead of the default

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2
```

I've done that, and no joy – after testing repeatedly with various tools ([here's a fast one](https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/poodle)), I find that SSLv3 is happily accepted by my server.

Yes, I did restart Apache. Yes, I did a recursive `grep` on all configuration files, and I don't have any override anywhere. And no, I'm not using some ancient version of Apache:

```
[root@server ~]# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 23 2014 14:17:29
```

So, what gives? How does one *really* disable SSLv3 in Apache?

Comment: Answered here: http://askubuntu.com/q/537196/7163

Comment: As explained in the question, I have performed all steps indicated in that section and SSL3 is still available. I couldn't tell you which specific part of that section fails to disable SSL3, but the point is that it just doesn't, in its entirety. Having said that, I understand you have your moderator hat on at the moment, so please unhold the question — it might well prove that I'm a moron and I made an elementary mistake, but from a moderator's POV this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I had the same problem...
You have to include `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3` within every VirtualHost stanza in httpd.conf

The VirtualHost stanzas are generally towards the end of the httpd.conf file. So for example:

```
...
...
<VirtualHost your.website.example.com:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/directory
    ServerName your.website.example.com

    ...
    SSLEngine on
    ...
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also check ssl.conf or httpd-ssl.conf or similar because they may be set there, not necessarily in httpd.conf

Comment: For the record, depending on your sysadmin/webmaster, VirtualHosts might just as well live within their own dedicated file in conf.d (that's how I like to keep house, and it's something I learned, not something I invented, so I expect I'm not the only one).

Comment: Note that as of at least Apache 2.4+ `SSLProtocol` configured outside of VirtualHost stanzas will apply to all virtual hosts.

Comment: I found this tool that will test, among other things, whether your server has SSLv3 disabled: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me when disabling TLSv1. To check if a given protocol is fully disabled, I found the following useful: `nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <hostname>`.

Comment: Is there a way to set up the `SSLProtocol` system-wide, without having to edit each VirtualHost?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. After reading this, I edited the section "SSLProtocol" in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf`.

- from: `SSLProtocol all`
- to:  `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSV1`

But it didn't work. So I edited the following section too "SSLCipherSuite" in
`/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf`.

- from: `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5`
- to: `SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SSLv3:!SSLv2:!TLSv1`

And now it now works for me.

By the way, the Cipher Suites are not affected by POODLE, only the protocol -- but most browsers are okay with a disabled SSLv3 Cipher Suite.

Don't use this for a Mailserver! Or you will (maybe) face the problem of not being able to fetch your Mails on some devices.

Comment: Thank you. This answer worked in WHM/cPanel setup. I tried other methods suggested online and yours was the only one that worked.

Comment: This works, but it will disable access with IE 10, as it uses SSLv3 and TLS1.0 by default.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 10.04

To disable SSLv3 on all active vhosts you need the option in

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf :**

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem this morning, and I found another virtualhost enabling SSLv3, so the entire server responds to SSLv3 connections.

So, make sure that none of your hosts has SSLv3 active.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the SSLCipherSuite *does not* contain !SSLv3.  In that context, it also refers to TLS1.0 and TLS1.1.

For example, if your config is *SSLProtocol All*, only TLS1.2 will be available due to how SSLCipherSuite is configured with !SSLv3.

Answer (score 0):

The method which you are using is for new version of Apache and Openssl. It might be possible that new version of these doesn't installed on your system, verify current installed version.

Since `SSLv2` and `SSLv3` both are vulnerable of some attacks, so it would be better to use only TLS. So modify your apache conf file as follows,

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
```

or

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried that – no joy. :-(

Comment: can you please paste the output of "apachectl configtest" command.

Answer (score 0):

For CentOs users having trouble editing your SSL configuration file via SSH, **try disabling SSLv3 via WHM**:

**Step 1: Navigate to the Include Editor**

-Login to WHM
-Open up the "Apache Configuration" screen, and click on "Include Editor"

**Step 2: Edit the Includes**

-Under "Pre Main Include", select "All Versions". This way your server will be protected if you change your version of Apache. When selected, enter the following into the text box:

**On CentOS/RHEL 6.x:**

SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

**On CentOS/RHEL 5.x:**

SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1

…and then click **Update**.

**Once you click update, you’ll be prompted to restart Apache; do so at this time.**

original source: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-disable-sslv3-and-protect-your-whmcpanel-server-from-poodle/

Comment: This answer is relevant for servers controlled via WHM/cPanel, not for servers running CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I had checked that I had all the appropriate apache settings correct.

However what I missed was that I had nginx as a reverse proxy in front of apache. I also happen to be using Plesk and this is from their [POODLE fixes guide](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213410909):

> If you are running Nginx, include the following line in your configuration among the other SSL directives in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` :

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```