# Still vulnerable after disabling SSLv3

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, poodle

I'm trying to disable SSLv3 to avoid the Poodle problem. I'm using the following instructions as a guidleine: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1232413

I've applied the following line to my config file:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

and restarted apache, but it looks like I'm still vulnerable. I'm using this tool to verify: https://access.redhat.com/labs/poodle/

I've also done a grep to make sure SSL is not active anywhere else, which it isn't.

I came across this post: [How to disable SSLv3 in Apache?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162478/poodle-disabling-sslv3-in-apache), the accepted answer states that you have to put in the above line in every vhost stanza, is this true? I do have other vhosts on this server but they are required to be secure.

** EDIT: Adding sanatised config file for the site with SSL references. **

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xxxxxx.xxx
    DocumentRoot "/html/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx"
    ServerAlias xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx
    ServerAlias xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx
    ServerName xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx
    ErrorLog logs/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx-error_log
    CustomLog logs/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@xxxxxx.xxx
        DocumentRoot "/html/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx”
        ServerAlias xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx
        ServerAlias xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx
        ServerName xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx
        ErrorLog logs/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx-error_log
        CustomLog logs/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx-access_log common

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx.ca

        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
        TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
        LogLevel warn

        <Directory "/html/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx">
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
                Options -Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

My other vhost files are just standard configs for port 80, there's nothing special about them.

sudo service httpd configtest returns Syntax OK.

Comment: Could you use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ instead and verify.

Comment: @Braiam I just tested the above link and I'm still vulnerable.

Comment: Could you provide, the version of apache and a sanitinized copy of your httpd.conf files? Might be good also `sudo apache2ctl configtest`

Comment: @Braiam details added.

Comment: "put in the above line in every vhost stanza" I believe is true only if each vhosts has 'SSLProtocol' stated separately, which I believe is not true in your case. Could you check whether there are any other ssl.conf files on your server?

Comment: @Sree I've done a grep and I can only find SSLProtocol in the mod_ssl.so and the one vhost (shown above).

Comment: Did you check whether there are more than one config files and that you are modifying the correct one? I assume that you have already restarted/reloaded apache after making the change.

Comment: @Sree I have five vhosts on this server and I'm modifying the correct one. I've used grep to make sure there are no others files hidden away.

Comment: This is strange. Could you confirm you have restarted/reloaded apache?

Comment: @Sree, yes I've done both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, I had to put the following line:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

For some reason the settings in the vhost config where not taking priority.

Answer (score 0):

One way i used to locate all HTTPS vhost is to recursive grep all the config files under httpd/apache2 dir.

```
/etc/apache2# grep -nR 'SSLEngine on' .
```

Comment: I used the following: sudo grep -r -i 'SSLProtocol' /etc/httpd and it just returned results in mod_ssl and my vhost config file.

Comment: Above command just returns results in my vhost file.

Comment: grep for `'SSLEngine on'` not `'SSLProtocol'`

Comment: I did it just returned the one result.